# Beautiful Soup Python Installation Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, installation, pycharm

I've been trying everything for the past hour to install beautiful soup.

I installed using the following and it does not work

1) download package
2) go to source folder in terminal and install using pip setup.py install

Setup is successful and I get Writing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.7.egg-info

However when I import using PyCharm, I get the following error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 896, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1136, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1112, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1093, in _legacy_get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 444, in spec_from_loader
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 530, in spec_from_file_location
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0-py3.5.egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 48
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also tried the above using python3 and 2to3 to account for using python3.5. This shouldn't be and issue as beautiful soup is compatible with python 3 now.

Comment: Do you have python 3 added to your path variable? If python 2 is in your path variable, it will use pip with python 2 and install packages for that version.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you install the wrong version of BeautifulSoup package.

> You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3

You can reinstall the BeautifulSoup package using `pip` like

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or using `easy_install`

```
easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

or using `pip` with downloaded [binary package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)

```
pip install beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

You can also checkout [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) for more details

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think I installed the correct version in terminal, but the package in PyCharm is outdated. Is it possible the two are different?

Comment: I guess you may have two versions of Python installed in your machine. If the installed BeautifulSoup package is version-correct, then there maybe some wrong with your PyCharm Python interpreter. You can check the project setting for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1) Select your project and press ctrl + Alt + s (To open settings).
2) Go to project untitled and then to project interpreter.
3) click on the + symbol at the right to install the required package.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: I checked the project inspector and it says that the beautiful soup package is installed. However when I run from bs4 import BeautifulSoup it returns the above error.

Comment: Your PyCharm run configuration might be using a different Python than the "Project Interpreter". Go to Run -> Edit Configurations and see which Python is being used.